# Script broken by Internet Explorer 9.. Won't even work in compatibility

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

My slideshow plugin for WordPress has been broken by Internet Explorer 9. It functions correctly in all other browsers, even Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8 but oddly not in Internet Explorer 9 using compatibility modes Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer  8! It seems as though the new browser just rejects the script entirely, and doesn't want to work.

The issue appears to be with the preloading functionality. The slideshow preloads the images before fading out a div and displaying them. In Internet Explorer 9, it just continuous loads but the images do show if you refresh the page, but not until.

You can see the scripts below:

http://pastebin.com/re9mmem0

You can also view a live example here:

http://premiumslider.matthewruddy.com/

*EDIT: The issue is really odd. I pulled out my old laptop and installed Internet Explorer 9, and it works perfectly on it. I made sure the two are using the same versions and they are (RTM 9.0.8112.16421).

Could this be a graphics card issue even with the way Internet Explorer 9 using graphics acceleration, etc.? The laptop, which it isn't working on, is using the new Intel HD 3000 graphics used in the [Sandy Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandy_Bridge) processors. Other is an ATI Mobility card.

Comment: Seems to work fine on my IE9 (although it's not as smooth as IE8 or Firefox).  Could some addons in your install cause issues?

Comment: Just added to the original post. I've just tried it on my old laptop and its work perfectly also, but not on my new laptop. Really odd. Its not just me though as people have been constantly emailing me about the issue also.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but i experienced an IE9 issue today with broken scripts, seems that my IE9 had scripts automatically disabled - way to go Microsfftpfft..

While in IE9 press F12 for dev tools , go to Disable tab, ensure that Scripts are not set to disabled.

Regards